# How to restore fragment views state after returning from back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, restore

I have `Fragment` which I replace by another one. I put transaction to backstack so I can move back later. If I press back button `saveInstanceState` `Bundle` of restored `Fragment` is null in it's methods cause `saveInstanceState` method of `Fragment` is actually called when parent `Activity` instance destroyed. So how I must restore `Fragment` state after returning it from backstack?

Comment: Are you using setRetainInstance(true) in the fragment you put in backstack?

Comment: No, as far as I know it prevents fragment from switching resources on config change.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem then. You want to restore the fragment that was put in the backstack, even when the configuration never changed (onSaveInstanceState() not called)? You don't need to restore it, the fragment instance still exists, only its view hierarchy was destroyed.

Comment: That's what  I mean - I need to restore views state. You know - textm scroll positions etc.

Comment: You can try to save that manually in onDestroyView() and restore it in onCreateView().

Answer (score 0):

This problem was mostly related to `ListViews`. I have found a solution in more correct managing of adapter data. I had local `mAdapter` variable in my `Fragment` which was created, populated with data and set to `ListView` in `onResume()` method of my `Fragment`. I have found solution in moving this code into `onActivityCreated()` method.